# How to create testcase for those method

Tags: python, mocking, testcase

I have two method and here is test i have done for feedback_selected_material_to_unsplash. I need to convert this test into  using mock and also i'm not sure how to write properly test for download_image_material. I appreciate for any help

Here is the testcase

```
def test_feedback_selected_material_to_unsplash_download_location_not_null(self, mock_post):
        URL = 'https://material.richka.co/track/unsplash'
        data = {
            'download_location': self.download_location
        }
        resp = requests.post("www.someurl.com", data=json.dumps(data), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
        mock_post.assert_called_with(URL, data=json.dumps(data), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})

def feedback_selected_material_to_unsplash(download_location):
    if not download_location == 'null':
        URL = 'https://test/track/unsplash'
        data = {
            'download_location': download_location
        }
        try:
            response = requests.post(URL, data)
            logger.info(response.json())
            logger.info('Done the feedback to unsplash.com')
        except:
            pass
```

this method i dont know how to write testcase for this

```
def download_image_material(request, data, video, keyword, keyword_gui, material_type):
    dname_tmp = settings.BASE_DIR + '/web/static'
    hashedDname = get_path_stock_box()
    saveFolder = gen_hash(gen_fname())
    path = '%s/%s/%s' % (dname_tmp, hashedDname, saveFolder)
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)
    objs = []
    material = Material(generated_video_data=video, keyword = keyword)
    material.is_video = material_type
    material.save()

    for index,datum in enumerate(data):
        if index == 50:
            break
        obj = {}
        obj['word'] = datum['word']
        obj['link'] = datum['link']
        obj['user'] = datum['user']
        obj['download_location'] = datum['download_location'] if 'unsplash.com' in datum['link'] else None
        imgUrl = datum['small']
        try:
            headers = {}
            response, imgRaw = http_get(imgUrl, headers=headers)
        except urllib.error.HTTPError as ex:
            continue
        except:
            continue

        imgUrlWithoutQuery = re.sub(r'\?.*','',imgUrl)
        suffix = imgUrlWithoutQuery[imgUrlWithoutQuery.rfind('.') + 1 :]
        suffix = suffix.lower()
        if suffix in settings.IMG_EXTENSIONS or suffix in settings.VIDEO_EXTENSIONS or suffix.lower() == 'mp4':
            pass
        else:
            mime = response.info()['Content-Type']
            suffix = _mime2suffix(mime)
            if suffix not in settings.IMG_EXTENSIONS and suffix not in settings.VIDEO_EXTENSIONS or suffix.lower() == 'mp4':
                continue

        imgFname = '%s.%s' % (gen_hash(gen_fname()), suffix)
        imgPathFname = '%s/%s/%s/%s' % (dname_tmp, hashedDname, saveFolder, imgFname)
        imgPathFnameSaved = '%s/%s/%s' % (hashedDname, saveFolder, imgFname)
        fout = open(imgPathFname, 'wb')
        fout.write(imgRaw)
        fout.close()

        #process file
        obj['media'] = imgPathFnameSaved
        if suffix in settings.IMG_EXTENSIONS:
            save_image_with_resize_and_rotate(imgPathFname)
            obj['media'] = imgPathFnameSaved
        elif suffix.lower() in settings.VIDEO_EXTENSIONS:
            # convert videos to mp4 and delete original files
            upload.conv2mp4(path)
            os.remove(path)

            hashed_name = imgPathFnameSaved[ : imgPathFnameSaved.rfind('.')] + '.mp4'
            obj['media'] = hashed_name

        if suffix == 'mp4':
            obj['video'] = {}
            obj['video']['duration'] = gen.get_video_duration(settings.BASE_DIR + '/web/static/' + obj['media'])

            gen_thumbnail(settings.BASE_DIR + '/web/static/' + obj['media'])
            fname_mp4 = obj['media']
            obj['media'] = fname_mp4[ : fname_mp4.rfind('.')] + '.png'

        #process service name
        url = urlparse(datum['link'])
        obj['service'] = {}
        obj['service']['url'] = f'{url.scheme}://{url.netloc}'
        obj['service']['hostname'] = url.netloc
        # get json from database
        material = Material.objects.get(id=material.pk)
        objDb = material.get_json_data()
        objs = []
        if objDb:
            for objOld in objDb:
                objs.append(objOld)
        objs.append(obj)
        material.set_json_data(objs)
        material.save()

        res_json = {'result': True, 'data':obj, 'keyword': keyword_gui, 'pk': material.pk}
        yield json.dumps(res_json) + '\n'
    material.set_json_data(objs)
    material.save()
    yield json.dumps({'result': True, 'end': True, 'pk': material.pk}) + '\n'
```

Comment: Not an answer, but an advice: no man should write unit tests for that monster function. Refactor it into a dozen functions and testing those would be no brainer.

Comment: @ipaleka thanks for your advice. I appreciate that

Comment: And about first question, If that is pytest-mock package included, your second argument should be something like `mocker`, and then inside the function you create mock with `mock_post = mocker.patch("mymodule.myclass.feedback_selected_material_to_unsplash")`. But your testing function and actual function are wrong, they switched places, actual calls go to function, and dummy into testing function.